# htaccess redirects with special characters on an specific url not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some help creating a redirect, I'm trying to replace all `-` to `+`, but both are special characters and also want to do it only when the URL contains `?s=`.

This is an example

```
example.com/?s=i-need-to-rewrite-this-url
example.com/?s=i+need+to+rewrite+this+url
```

This is what I have, I already tried to use `()` or `""` but didn't work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^?s=(.*)\-(.*)$ ?s=$1\+$2 [L,R=301]
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to replace all `-` to `+`, but both are special characters

There's nothing particularly "special" about these characters. At least, not in the context they are going to be used. The `-` (hyphen) is a *range specifier* when used inside a regex character class, otherwise it's just a hyphen and safe to use unencoded in the query string part of the URL (we do not *need* to use it in a regex character class). The `+` (plus) is a regex quantifier, but we don't need to use it in a regex, only in the *substitution string* (2nd argument to the `RewriteRule` directive, which is not a regex). The `+` is an encoded *space* when used in the query string part of the URL - which I guess you are aware of and is why you need to redirect the request (although since this is part of a URL parameter value, it's also curious why this can't be resolved in the application).

One thing of note, however, is that since `+` is a URL encoded *space* we do need to use the `NE` (`noescape`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive to prevent mod_rewrite from URL encoding the `+` as `%2B` (a literal `+`) in the redirect response. (The same goes for any other %-encoded characters we might capture from the `QUERY_STRING` - this server variable is not %-decoded.)

> ```
> RewriteRule ^?s=(.*)\-(.*)$ ?s=$1\+$2 [L,R=301]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) matches against the URL-path only, not the query string. So, a `RewriteRule` directive alone will never match the query string. Incidentally, `?` is a special regex character (0 or 1 quantifier of the preceding token) and `^` (the preceding token) is not quantifiable, so I would be surprised whether this would even compile (resulting in a 500 Internal Server Error). A literal `?` in a regex needs to be backslash-escaped.

As mentioned above, the `NE` flag would be required here. And the `+` does not need to be backslash-escaped in the *substitution string*, since it carries no special meaning here (it's not a regex). Also, due to the relative *substitution string* (ie. `?s=$1\+$2`), unless you have a `RewriteBase` defined this would have resulted in a malformed redirect.

To match against the query string you need an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. So, as a first attempt, you could do something like this:

```
# First attempt (inefficient when multiple "-" are present)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&]*)-([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^$ /?s=%1+%2 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Note that the `%1` and `%2` backreferences (as opposed to `$1`, etc.) contain the values captured from the preceding *CondPattern* (`RewriteCond` directive), rather than the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (which in this case just matches the empty string).

(NB: You should always test first with 302 - temporary - redirects to avoid potential caching issues and make sure any intermediary caches are cleared before testing.)

I'm assuming `s` is the *only* URL parameter. With the above rule, any other URL params that follow will be discarded.

*HOWEVER*, the above is very inefficient since it triggers an external redirect for every instance of `-`. So, your example of `/?s=i-need-to-rewrite-this-url` would trigger 5 redirects.

## Solution

Instead of the above you should recursively replace all-but-one `-` internally and only trigger the external redirect (and replace the last `-`) once all the `-` have been replaced. For this we need an additional rewrite to perform the internal replacements. For example:

```
# Internally replace all but the last "-" with "+" in the URL param
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&]*-[^&]*){2}
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&]*)-([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^$ ?s=%1+%2 [N=20]

# Replace the last "-" and redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&-]*)-([^&-]*)
RewriteRule ^$ /?s=%1+%2 [NE,R=301,L]
```

The first *condition* that checks against the regex `^s=([^&]*-[^&]*){2}` simply determines that there are at least 2 hyphens in the value of the `s` URL parameter. (Otherwise the rule is skipped and goes straight to the second/redirect rule.) The second *condition* then captures the relevant parts of the query string around the last `-`, which are then used in the following `RewriteRule`.

The `N` flag causes the rewrite engine to immediately start over. The `20` sets a limit on the number of iterations (Apache 2.4+) - so I'm assuming no more than 20+1 hyphens (the last hyphen is replaced in the second/redirect rule).

Since we know there is only going to be at most 1 hyphen remaining in the URL parameter when the second rule is processed, I added the hyphen to the regex character class as an *optimisation*, to avoid unnecessary backtracking.

---

#### Future

There is a [`replace` function coming to Apache expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html#functions), that (as the name suggests) allows you to search/replace chars in a string, but I don't think this has shipped yet in the latest public builds. But this would potentially allow you to do something like the following in a single rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=[^&]*-
RewriteCond expr "replace(%{QUERY_STRING},'-','+') =~ /^s=([^&]+)/"
RewriteRule ^$ /?s=%1 [NE,R=301,L]
```